# Add / use custom SVG as material-icon

Tags: angular-material, angular-dart

I'm using the material design package for my application layout menu.
I have 2 menus items where I can't find an icon that fits, so I got 2 SVG files that I added to the project.
I want to use this as the material-list-item icon instead of a material-icon.
Is there a way to do this by either adding a custom icon to the material-icon library or replacing the icon in the list.
If yes, please I need a complete example as I am new to DartAngular, still trying to figure out some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mixin for material-icon which will get allow you to change a material-icon into using an SVG. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/c6cb3d783e72ff1ed7974f18b7f169778c73d39b/angular_components/lib/material_icon/_mixins.scss#L49

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a mixin for this as pointed out in [Ted Sander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54206837/405481), but for the moment it does not seem to work. I've asked this on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/dart-lang/angular) but did not get an answer, and I also opened a [ticket on Github](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/384) for this seemingly broken feature.

It's a telltale sign that even the official Angular Components Gallery has a [broken SVG icon example](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_icon).

I'd suggest to implement this by using separate list item rendering for those that have an official `material-icon` representation and those that need a custom SVG image, and conditionally render them with the `ngIf` directive.